# Mysqli Prepared Statement Troubleshooting

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm stumped,  I recently had this working in plain Mysqli statements, but was told to avoid injection to write it using prepared statements.  The truncate is the only thing that seems to work.  Any advice?

```
$con=mysqli_connect(localhost,"username","password","db");


// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
 {
 echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
 }

$deletetable = $con->prepare('TRUNCATE TABLE twitch_streams');
$deletetable->execute();
$deletetable->close();

$result = $con->prepare("SELECT field_value
FROM xf_user_field_value
WHERE field_id = 'twitch'
AND field_value != ''");

$result->bind_result($twitchfield);

while($result->fetch())
{
printf("%s\n", $twitchfield);
$username[] = $twitchfield;
$data =    json_decode(file_get_contents('http://api.justin.tv/api/stream/l   ist.json?channel=' . $username[0]));
$viewer[] = $data[0]->channel_count;


$insert = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO twitch_streams (twitchuser, viewercount)
VALUES (?, ?)");
$insert->bind_param('si', $twitchuser, $viewercount);

$twitchuser = $username[0];
$viewercount = $viewer[0];

$insert->execute();

echo $twitchuser;
echo $viewercount;
$insert->close();
  }

$result->close();$deletetable = $con->prepare('TRUNCATE TABLE twitch_streams');
$deletetable->execute();
$deletetable->close();

$result = $con->prepare("SELECT field_value
FROM xf_user_field_value
WHERE field_id = twitch
AND field_value != ''");

$result->bind_result($twitchfield);

while($result->fetch())
  {
   printf("%s\n", $twitchfield);
   $username[] = $twitchfield;
   $data =    json_decode(file_get_contents('http://api.justin.tv/api/stream/l   ist.json?      channel=' . $username[0]));
$viewer[] = $data[0]->channel_count;


$insert = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO twitch_streams (twitchuser, viewercount)
VALUES (?, ?)");
$insert = bind_param('si', $twitchuser, $viewercount);

$twitchuser = $username[0];
$viewercount = $viewer[0];

$insert->execute();

echo $twitchuser;
echo $viewercount;
$insert->close();
  }

$result->close();
mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: Check your error_log and see if there is any other errors present.

Comment: Checked with that one mistake and still no output.  Doesn't seem like $result statement works either.

Answer (score 3):

There is no function `bind_param()`, it is a method of **mysqli_stmt**

You use it like so:

`$insert->bind_param()`

Check [here](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) for more information on **mysqli_stmt**